# How to close port after using server sockets

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

In my application I create a `ServerSocket` instance with some port. After I am finished, I close the socket, but when I try to make a new `ServerSocket` on the same port, it throws:

```
"java.net.BindException: Address already in use"
```

If I create the `ServerSocket` with a different port, then it works.

`ServerSocket.isClosed` also returns true

What is the problem?

```
public void run() {
    try {
        BufferedInputStream bufferedinputstream = new BufferedInputStream(
                                                        new FileInputStream(fileReq));
        BufferedOutputStream outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                                                        cs.getOutputStream());
        byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];

        int read;
        System.out.println(cs);
        while ((read = bufferedinputstream.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
            outStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
            outStream.flush();
        }
        System.out.println("File transfered");
        outStream.close();
        bufferedinputstream.close();

        try {
            this.finalize();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exce....");
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
finally
{
    if ( cs != null)
        try {
            int usedPort=cs.getLocalPort();
            System.out.println("Closing "+cs);
            cs.close();
            System.out.println(cs+" Closed");
            System.out.println("asd"+cs.isClosed());
            portManager.getInstance().mp.put(usedPort,true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("in sendToClient can't close sockt");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried calling `setReuseAddress(true)` on the server socket? It's normal for the TCP state machine to enter `TIME_WAIT` state. For detailed explanation look [here](http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/addrinuse.html).

Comment: first thanks for the help all of you. and yes i tried this (i need you use it when the socket is start right?) any way it's not work the deam port allways in in use "Address already in use: JVM_Bind" grrr how its can possible that i can't use that port all over the program run until i close the java program.. must be a some way

Comment: What platform is it? If it's Linux, try netstat -pan | grep 1234 and see the state. On windows you can try netstat -an as well.

Answer (score 1):

It is because there is a cooldown period implemented on some O.S. If you wait a little (a couple of minutes for example), then you should be able to access the port again.

That being said, it is not a good idea to open and close serversockets on a port. It is better to open it and keep it open as long as necessary. Then close it when you are done. Don't open/close/open/close/open/close...

Comment: i wait for 10 min but still it's not let mt use this port agien until i close my server program...

Answer (score 0):

Just close the socket when done.  It automatically shuts down the port it is listening on.  Never keep open the socket (port) when you are done.

Comment: well this what i'm doing(like you can see in my code)... but it's not helping!!!! i try evrey thing to free this port..

Answer (score -2):

This means that the server is already open you need a check for user input or client input that says close the server like

```
while( bufferedinputstream != "quit" )

try{

...

}
```

Once you have the server open its just open until something closes it.

Comment: `BuuferedInputStreams` are never equal to `Strings`, and `==` is not the correct way to test that even if they were.