# What happens to ServerSocket when InetAddress changes?

Tags: android, sockets, serversocket, tcp

I am writing an Android application, which has `ServerSocket` accepting connection from client. Now, when IP changes (due to device going on & off to diffrernt network interface), what happens to `SocketServer` ? What I seeing is that connection stays up and I do receive message but once a while when my application crashes and reboots, I see Socket BindException: Address already in use. I am closing sockets on `onPause()`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147481/how-to-close-port-after-using-server-sockets/6150001#6150001

Comment: If your application keeps working after an IP address change, that's not what your question is about.

Answer (score -1):

You need to call [`setReuseAddress( true )`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setReuseAddress%28boolean%29) on the server socket before calling the [`bind()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#bind%28java.net.SocketAddress%29).

Comment: You have to use default constructor of `ServerSocket`, then `setReuseAddress()`, then `bind()`.

Comment: Yes, I am using the default constructor.

Comment: Ok So i was able to fix the issue. However, I have another issue. And I think this is the root cause of it. Is there any way we can reconfigure ServerSocket ?

Comment: No, you have to create a new one.