# How to close a server port after we are done using it?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, server

Note: I found a similar question here:

[How to close port after using server sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147481/how-to-close-port-after-using-server-sockets)

But did not find any satisfactory answer there.

Here is my code for the client program:

```
package hf;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class DailyAdviceClient 
{
    private static final int chatPort = 4242;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DailyAdviceClient client = new DailyAdviceClient();
        client.go();
    }

    private void go()
    {
        try
        {
            Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1",chatPort);
            InputStreamReader inputStream = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStream);

            String advice = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println("Advice received by the client for today is "+advice);

            bufferedReader.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Failed to connect to the server");
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code for the server program:

```
package hf;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class DailyAdviceServer 
{
    private String[] adviceList = {"Take smaller bites",
            "Go for the tight jeans. No they do NOT make you look fat.",
            "One word: inappropriate", 
            "Just for today, be honest. Tell your boss what you *really* think", 
            "You might want to rethink that haircut."};
    private static final int chatPort = 4242;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DailyAdviceServer server = new DailyAdviceServer();
        server.go();
    }

    private void go()
    {
        try
        {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(chatPort);

            while(true)
            {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

                String advice = getTodaysAdvice();

                writer.println(advice);
                writer.close();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error in establishing connection with the client");
        }
    }

    private String getTodaysAdvice()
    {
        String advice = null;

        int randomIndex = (int) (Math.random()*adviceList.length);
        advice = adviceList[randomIndex];
        return advice;
    }
}
```

In the application, whenever a client program connects to the server program, it receives a String that contains advice for the day.

When I run

```
netstat -an
```

In the command prompt of my Windows computer as suggested in one of the answers in the aforementioned link, I get a message that the port 4242 is

```
LISTENING
```

How do I close the port and make it available for future re-use?

Comment: as long as the server is running, the port will be open, until someone stops the server. you should close the sockets from both server and client with socket.close() after you are done reading or writing; but the line ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(chatPort); will always keep that port used by the server

Comment: @MihaiC No it won't. It will keep it listening until the server socket is closed or the process exits. 'Always' is a long time.

Comment: @Luke OMG another one. That was not a link-only answer. Did you read it?

Comment: @EJP that's exactly what i said. "until someone stops the server" = process exits, and "ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(chatPort);" will keep it open until the serversocket is closed...

Comment: @MihaiC 'Will always keep the port used by that server' is 'exactly what you said' and is exactly what I am commenting on.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the LISTENING port you have to call `serverSocket.close().`

Comment: ,I want the port to be active as long as I am running the server-side program. And then want the port to be freed once, I have stopped running the server side program.I will not be able to put in the line serverSocket.close() in my server-side program, because that would imply that the server-side program, stops running on its own, rather than being available as long as it is being run. I have run this via Eclipse IDE.The console in the IDE does not show any running program, even when the selected editor window is of the server-side program,which leads me to presume that it has terminated.

Comment: So, it appears that the port is still LISTENING , despite being terminated. I have 4 questions.1)Is there any place where I can put in serverSocket.close() in the program, without affecting the desired functionality of the server-side program?2)Does terminating the server-side program explicitly free the port?3)How do I terminate/stop the server-side program from running in Eclipse IDE?4)How do I know whether the program is terminated?(As I previously mentioned the console displays the message terminated. But if that is the case, then I don't understand why the port is still listening if the)

Comment: continued...server-side program has been terminated.

Comment: I've answered your question. The port will be LISTENING until the process exits or you close the `ServerSocket.` Only you know when you want to do that.

Comment: If I do not include serverSocket.close() in the server-side code and want to kill the process explicitly from outside, how do I do it in Eclipse IDE? If I select the tab, that contains the code for server-side code, it does not show that the code is still running, although it is. Please can you tell me how to stop the server-side program from running explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `socket.close()` after closing the `writer` and `bufferedReader`. So the Port will be free for another communication.

Comment: You don't 'have to use `socket.close()` after closing the writer and buffered reader', as closing either will close the other and the socket, and the port is available for another communication whether you close that socket or not.